# How do I put a Micro-SD card into a slot for SD/MMC/SDHC?

Tags: sd-card, micro-sd-card

An electronic picture frame has a lot for  SD/MMC/SDHC. A Micro-SD card came with it and is supposed to go there, but is clearly too small for the slot. How do I insert this card?  There is no apparent micro-sized slot inside that larger slot.

[image: Photo of slot and card]

Comment: With the appropriate adapter? For example [MICRO SD TO SD CARD ADAPTOR](http://www.amazon.co.uk/MICRO-SD-TO-CARD-ADAPTOR/dp/B0019AJJRK), less than 1UKP ;)

Comment: Did you check in the box for an adapter?

Comment: If not, you should boycott the vendor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the picture frame *should* have come with an adapter to convert that MicroSD card into an SD card. They are very cheap online and come with almost any microSD card new.

[image: Here's a picture of the adapter]

Comment: Thanks. I actually looked for an adapter and there was none. I'll get one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy an adapter. It's about $4 [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047WZOOO), and I'm sure you can find cheaper on eBay